# Regex to replace hash-enclosed `##WORD=123##` to square bracketed`[object word=123]`

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace hashtags with square brackets and add a word after the first square bracket and all string need to be lower case.

Example string :

```
$str = "This is some text  
<p>##IDOBJECT=784##</p> and another some text 
<p>##IDOBJECT=1509##</p>
<p>##LATESTARTICLESHOME=321##</p>
<p align=\"center\">##IDOBJECT=321##</p>";
```

I want to replace `##IDOBJECT=123##` formated strings with `[object idobject=123]`. Note that here extra `object` word added after first `[` bracket and `IDOBJECT` string converted to `idobject` . 
I tried this `/(\##.*?\##)/`  regex to find those strings but unable to replace as I described.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to give you a regex until you explain conversions. Is that a miscellaneous thing or what ? Is it something that has to be there, does `=` need to be parsed ... ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is correct, you just need to adjust where you capture. Move the group inside the `#`s. Also `#` isn't special so it doesn't need to be escaped.

```
##(.*?)##
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/meYYna/1/

... or I may have misread, if you want to lowercase the return as well use `preg_replace_callback` with `strtolower`.

```
$str = "This is some text  
<p>##IDOBJECT=784##</p> and another some text 
<p>##IDOBJECT=1509##</p>
<p>##LATESTARTICLESHOME=321##</p>
<p align=\"center\">##IDOBJECT=321##</p>";
echo preg_replace_callback('/##(.*?)##/', function($match){
    return strtolower('[object ' . $match[1] . ']');
}, $str);
```

https://3v4l.org/ijZiO